# Check Excel cell for specific text-part

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to create a function that assigns a 1 to the column "independent" if a part in the column "BoardRole" contains "Independent" and it doesn't matter what's before or behind it, and a 0 otherwise. Can somebody maybe help me out?

For clarification, I added a print screen to this post.

[image: Excel screen]

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239)

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Answer (score 0):

The piece of information you're missing is the [FIND()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-findb-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628) or [SEARCH()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/search-searchb-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495) function. They are very similar but there are some differences. SEARCH() is newer, case-insensitive, and accepts wildcards. I suggest using SEARCH() here since you likely don't care about case.

```
=SEARCH(E3673,"Independent")
```

This will return either a number indicating the starting position of the word or, if it is not found, it will return an error. You want either `1` or `0`, though, so we can do this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(E3673,"Independent")),0,1)
```

This returns `0` if the text is not found and `1` if it is. There are fancier ways to do this but this method is the most straightforward.

---

Note: I've used the cell `E3673` in the formula because that's the first row shown in your screenshot. If you put this formula into cell `I2`, you  should change the cell reference to `E2`. It will automatically update once you copy/paste it down to fill the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible with a workaround, because Excel does not allow wildcards for IF function.

The Excel SEARCH function returns the location of one text string inside another. SEARCH returns the position of find_text inside within_text as a number. SEARCH supports wildcards ***in a limited way***, and is not case-sensitive.

ISNUMBER returns TRUE for numbers and FALSE for anything else. If SEARCH finds the substring, it returns the position as a number, and ISNUMBER returns TRUE.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Independent",E2)),1,0)
```

**OR** for a special use:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Ind?pendent",E2)),1,0)
```

You still need to customize this for your needs.

[image]

For further information about using wildcards see [Dave's ExcelJet](https://exceljet.net/functions/search-function).

Answer (score 0):

There are two search-functions in Excel: `Search()` is already described in the other answers, but this is a formula, based on the `FIND()` Excel function:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("INDEPENDENT",UPPER(A1))),"whatever",0)
```

As you see, `FIND()` is case sensitive, so you need to work with capitals in order to be sure to find it case-insensitively.

Screenshot of an example:

[image]